# spring and @transactional, is this normal?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactional

i wrote this simple example:

```
//file TestController.java
public interface TestController {

    public List<Test> findAll();

}

//file TestControllerImp.java
@Controller
public class TestControllerImp implements TestController{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
    }

    public List<Test> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Test").list();
    }

}

//file TestService.java
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestController controller;

    public boolean flag=true;

    public void setController(TestController controller){
        this.controller=controller;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Test> useController(){
        flag=false;
        return controller.findAll();
    }

}
```

And this is my try:

```
TestService s1=context.getBean(TestService.class);
TestService s2=context.getBean(TestService.class);
List<Test> list=s1.useController();
System.out.println(s1.flag+"  "+s2.flag);
```

Now the strange behaviour (im very new with spring):

1. If i declare `@Transactional` the method "useController()", the output is: true  true
2. If i move `@Transactional` from `TestService` to `TestControllerImp`, and i declare "findAll()" with `@Transactional`, the output is: false false.

Why i have this behaviour? I know by default `@Autowired` classes are singletone, but why in the first case the flag still remains true?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The @Transactional mechanism works on JDK proxies per default and those work on interfaces only.

So if you let `TestService` be an interface and `TestServiceImpl` be its implementation, then the above code should work.

e.g. change the class declaration to this:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
```

but the test code must reference the interface, not the class:

```
// this code remains unchanged
TestService s1=context.getBean(TestService.class);
TestService s2=context.getBean(TestService.class);
```

Reference:

- [`<tx:advice/>` settings](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-txadvice-settings) (Spring Reference)
- [Using `@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) (Spring Reference)
- [TransactionProxyFactorybean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionProxyFactoryBean.html) (javadoc)

Comment: So @Transactional only works if you're using it in an interface's implementation?

Comment: yes, unless you use `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />`. Then CGLIB will be used to create dynamic subclasses

Comment: @seanizer: Thank you, so for every service class i have to write interface and its implementation? Can i change default @Transactional mechanism? You say work on JDK but debugging s1 and s2 i see TestService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$51486891 so i think it work on CGLIB instead, isn't true?

Comment: @seanizer: i read now your comment, i use simply <tx:annotation-driven/> at this moment, mybew spring 3 use proxy-target-class="true" by default?

Comment: OK then maybe the public field is the problem. Try replacing it with a private field and a getter and see if it works then.

Comment: the default setting is proxy-target-class="false"

Comment: @seanizer: ok now the output is false false, but why s1 and s2 are CGLIB proxy based if i omitted proxy-target-class="true" on my <tx:annotation-driven/>? I read from reference: If proxy-target-class is false or if the attribute is omitted, then standard JDK interface-based proxies are created.

Comment: apparently there is a fallback mechanism to use CGLIB if there are no interfaces to proxy.

Comment: Ok, with an implementation of TestService all works in according to references. I have a simple question: what benefits can i have to write a service class with interface implementation instead a simple class without interface? If i change tecnlogy, for example from hibernate to JDBC, i have to simply add a DAO implementation, service layer is not touch, isn'true? So why should i write an interface for my services?

Comment: because coding against interfaces is generally more favorable, as it ties your code to a contract, not its implementation. Read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch for more detail.