# Spring Transactions not rolling back on Exception (Oracle JNDI datasource)

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc, jndi

I am using annotation based transactions in a Spring MVC 3.1 project, and my transactions are not being rolled back when an exception is thrown.

Here is my Service code

```
@Service
public class ImportService {

    @Autowired
    ImportMapper importMapper;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
    public void processImport() throws ServiceException, DatabaseException {
        iImport import = new Import();

        createImport(import);

        throw new ServiceException("");         
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
    private void createImport(Import import) throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            importMapper.createImport(eventImport);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(e);
        }
    }
```

So, hopefully, the createImport method should be rolled back after the exception is thrown.  But unfortunately it's not.

I am defining my datasource in the server context.xml

```
<Resource name="datasource.import" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="user" password="password" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
           url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@INFO" />
```

And I'm looking it up with JNDI:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="datasource.import"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

I'm using an Oracle database, and the JDBC spec says that auto commit is true by default.  I thought that if I set it to false explicitly that would help, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Is there any way to get rollbacks working, while looking up your Oracle datasource by JNDI.

Comment: I solved my issue, but the problem wasn't what I originally thought.  The transaction beans were defined in the wrong context file.  I had them in the root context.

This question helped me solve my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538345/spring-transactional-annotations-ignored

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the actual problem is not the one described in the text.

Answer (score 5):

Please be aware that Spring's transaction management rolls-back transactions only for unchecked exceptions (`RuntimeException`) by default. If you wish to perform rollback also on checked exceptions, you need to define that.

[When using annotations as attribute source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings), you need to provide `rollbackFor` attribute with the list of exception classes, which should cause a transaction to be rolled-back (quote from the JavaDoc):

```
/**
 * Defines zero (0) or more exception {@link Class classes}, which must be a
 * subclass of {@link Throwable}, indicating which exception types must cause
 * a transaction rollback.
 * <p>This is the preferred way to construct a rollback rule, matching the
 * exception class and subclasses.
 * <p>Similar to {@link org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RollbackRuleAttribute#RollbackRuleAttribute(Class clazz)}
 */
Class<? extends Throwable>[] rollbackFor() default {};
```

Comment: It is defined.  The Transactional annotation has rollbackFor=Throwable.class

Answer (score 0):

It is said that, if a @transational method is invoked by another @transational method, the first one will not work. You may try to remove the first @transational and have a try.